# Android binder security

Tags: android, security, android-binder

Is the interprocess communication provided by Binder in *Android* protected against man in the middle attacks? Is there any documentation that provides this info?

Answer (score 21):

Binder uses a capability-based security model.  Each binder object represents a capability; handing that object to another process grants the process access to that capability.  From that perspective, you prevent man in the middle attacks by not handing an important binder object to the man in the middle.  If a process doesn't get handed a binder object, it can not access it in any way.

Regarding the "cross-binder reference forgery" issue discussed in the paper, if I am understanding the specific scenario they are talking about, I think their addendum about user space is a little weaker than I would agree with.  They make the mistake I think of looking at the special C code written for the ServiceManager.  Formally, I would consider the C++ user space code (consisting in particular of Parcel) as being part of the Binder architecture.  This code in particular makes sure to deal with such attempts at spoofing when you call its readBinder() and related methods.

I don't agree with the statement that it is a flaw that the kernel is not completely ensuring integrity of the data.  The only way I could imagine for it to do that would be to defined a standard typed data structure for binder transactions, so that it could read and verify the contents of the parcel.  This puts too much knowledge in the kernel in my opinion, and for no real benefit.  No matter how much you put there, user space will need to do some kind of validation of the incoming transaction to ensure it matches its expectations.  Today this is done at the level of validating that primitive data read operations on Parcel (readBinder(), readString16(), readInt(), etc) are written to avoid attacks.  Pushing more validation to the kernel will still require validation in user space that data types are correct, and now you have actually moved some opportunities for attacks (due to bugs in this code) from user space to the kernel.

One final thing about binder security is that it is important to realize that at the platform level there is another important security model implemented on top of the binder infrastructure.  This is the permission/uid-based system, where services can check the uid of incoming calls to verify them against their allowed permissions.

This security model has another spoofing vulnerability that it must deal with.  A typical scenario would be an application receiving the IBinder for the Activity Manager Service (since everyone can get that).  The API of the Activity Manager Service is deeply based on checking the uid of incoming calls to determine what is allowed -- for example if a call to bindService() is made, it will check to see if that uid has permission to bind to the given service.  A malicious app could try to play games here by handing the activity manager IBinder to another system service, for example as an IWindow to the window manager.  If it knows the transactions that the second system service will make, it could set things up so that it makes a call that it thinks is say resizeWindow() but actually ends up becoming a call to bindService() when it comes put in the activity manager (if those two calls are mapped to the same transaction ID).

This vulnerability exists because the binder system is not typed in any way, "method" calls are simply transactions being sent with an integer transaction code and data buffer.

To protect against this, the user space typed interfaces generated by aidl always put at the start of their transaction buffer the name of the interface they are intending to call, and the receiving code of the transaction checks the interface name at the front of the buffer to ensure that it matches its own interace.  This way the spoofer in the scenario above will be caught when the activity manager sees that it has an incoming call whose interface was for a window.

Anyway, for most practical use by Android developers, uid-based security is just as relevant as the core binder capability model.  In some cases you will enforce security by restricting which processes get access to a binder.  An example for this would be how there is an IBinder representing each activity, which only the system process and the process running the activity share.

In other cases and IBinder object will be shared with any interested processes, but enforce security at point of call based on uid.  If you are using aidl to supply your standard implementation of such interfaces, your own implementation of such security can be done based on what meaning you want to apply to uids.  For example, you could use the standard facility to associated permissions with uids and ask the package manager if the incoming uid has a permission.

Comment: Thanks @hackbod this is very useful, in-depth documentation on Android's Binder mechanism. This should be attached to Binder's JavaDoc or something as its far more comprehensive than what is currently offered :-)

Comment: This is a very in-depth explaination, but I don't understand this paragraph:

The user space typed interfaces generated by aidl always put at the start of their transaction buffer the name of the interface they are intending to call, and the receiving code of the transaction checks the interface name at the front of the buffer to ensure that it matches its own interace.

I can't find that buffer in the generated file. Could you explain a bit more more?
Thank you so much.

Comment: @TranSonHai:  In the proxy (sender) part of the AIDL-generated Java file, you'll see `_data.writeInterfaceToken(DESCRIPTOR)` at the beginning of each method. `DESCRIPTOR` is the interface name, and `_data` is the transaction buffer used by `mRemote.transact`. On the stub (receiver) side of the same file, you'll see a call to `enforceInterface(DESCRIPTOR)` at the beginning of every transaction case.  This is where the check mentioned above is done. `_data` and `data` are objects of class `android.os.Parcel` and `mRemote` is of class `android.os.IBinder`.

Answer (score 2):

The Binder has one identified security flaw which may make it susceptible to a MITM attack: http://crypto.hyperlink.cz/files/xbinder.pdf . To quote TFA:

> the attacker can manage the target to further pass on or call its “protected” binder (that the attacker is not invited to call directly). We call this a cross-binder reference forgery (XBRF)

The author goes on to say that there are defenses in Android against this attack, but that

> in some situations, a careful manipulation with the transaction data prepared by an attacking process may still lead to a successful XBRF exploit

One gets the impression that Binder seems to be relatively secure for carefully-written code, but there is some risk.

Comment: This is a good answer for the original question. However, it doesn't answer how to authenticate both end-points of a binder communication.

Comment: According to TFA, there are some mitigation efforts in the Android code, but they are not necessarily sufficient. The remaining measure left to the developer is therefore to use a digital signature between communicating processes.